# Hack into the file!

Tags: cipher, password

You are a government worker. You have successfully intercepted a file from terrorists. But you need to put in a password. This is the only clue: 1 4 1 1 4
4 4 4 2 5 5 3 3 4 4 1  4 2 4 4 4 2 4 4

Hint:

> The cipher isn't A = 1  B = 2

I will post a new hint every day the puzzle isn't solved.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! You may want to read [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717) for some guidance on how to turn a cipher challenge into an interesting puzzle. Note that cipher puzzles in particular should incorporate clues to how they should be solved—as part of the puzzle itself, not grafted on in spoiler-tagged "hints". If the hint is effectively required for anyone not inside your head to solve the puzzle then it's not a "hint", it's an essential part of the puzzle--and is often the only thing preventing your puzzle from being "guess the cipher".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that each of the numbers is between $1$ and $5$, I believe this is related to

> [Tap Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tap_code)

And so

> Grouping the numbers in pairs we have $(1,4), (1,1), (4,4), (4,4), (2,5), (5,3), (3,4), (4,1), (4,2), (4,4), (4,2), (4,4)$

Then, applying these to the following grid

> [image]

Where

> We refer to the first coordinate as the column number and the second as the row number

We get

> PASSWORDISIS

Which translates as either

> "Password Isis" or "Password is 'is'"

Comment: Very good! But I used V/W instead of U/V. :p